# Android app error when use Promise while on background mode

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, promise

My goal is to delay a method for 1s. The Promise works great while in the Foreground Mode. If used while in the background mode, it will throw an unhandled promise.

The code

```
const recorderStop = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // used to delay.
  ... the code I wish to invoke...
}
```

**The expected behavior:**

The code wait for 1s before invoking the rest of the code.

**The actual behavior:**

The code freezes and waiting the `await new Promise` to return a promise until the app is in the Foreground Mode.

**Edit, tested code:**

1. setTimeout with return Promise

```
const recorderStop = async () => {
  console.log('before the setTimeout');
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  console.log('after the setTimeout'); // this code will not be invoked while in the background mode.
}
```

2. setTimeout without return Promise.

the code

```
const recorderStop = async () => {
  console.log('outside the timeout');
  setTimeout(async () => {
    console.log('inside timeout'); // this code is not invoked while in the background mode.
  }, 1000);
}
```

The output, `the console.log('inside timeout') is not invoked while in the background mode.`

```
[Sat Dec 12 2020 16:10:59.517]  LOG      recorder is recording
[Sat Dec 12 2020 16:11:01.980]  LOG      recorderStop(): outside timeout
```

Comment: Unless recorderStop's caller needs to know about eventual completion of the code, then you can use an un-promisified `setTimeout()`. In any case, you might try it to help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I think the problem is with `setTimeout`. I created a method with `setTimeout` with `console.log`, one outside the `setTimeout`, and one inside the `setTimeout`. If the app is in background mode, it refuse to run the `console.log` inside `setTimeout`.

Comment: Would have to guess that the js event loop is suspended in bg mode.